# Auto-populate fields in a form based on a select with data taken from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bootstrap-4, web-applications

I have done a web app with GAS that send the data on submit to a spreadsheet A.
There is also a select option that take some data dynamically from another spreadsheet B ("xxx") in column A.

This is the code:

**In Code.gs:**

```
function address() {
  var sheet   =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx").getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += '<option>' + data[i][0] + '</option>';
  };
  return optionsHTML;
}
```

**In Index.html:**

```
<select class="custom-select" name="test" id="test">
 <?!= address(); ?>
</select>
```

I would to auto-populate other to two fields in the form based on the Columns B e C corresponding to the value in Col A that is in the select option.

For example, if in the spreadsheet B ("xxx") in the select option I choose "Italy", there will be also two fields not editable by the user, with the data "Tom" and "Red" inside.

```
+-----------------------+---------+-------+
| Col A (Select Option) |  Col B  | Col C |
+-----------------------+---------+-------+
| Italy                 | Tom     | Red   |
| USA                   | Michael | Green |
| Africa                | Anna    | Blue  |
+-----------------------+---------+-------+
```

---

**(Output)**

[image: Output:]

How can I proceed?

**Update 1**
(I am trying with the solution of Tanaike)

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "xxxx";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  ws.appendRow([formObject.azienda,
                formObject.test,
                formObject.field1,
                formObject.field2]);
}

function address() {
  var sheet   =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx").getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + lastRow);  // Modified
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += `<option data-values="${data[i][1]},${data[i][2]}">${data[i][0]}</option>`;  // Modified
  };
  return optionsHTML;
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Contact Details</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label for="azienda">Azienda</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="azienda" name="azienda" required="">
                            </div>
                            
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                             <label for="test">Ateco 1</label>
                             <select class="custom-select" name="test" id="test">
                             <?!= address(); ?>
                             </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                            <label for="field1">Field1</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                            <label for="field2">Field2</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field2" name="field2" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Inserisci in Master Leads</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</html>
```

**Javascript.html**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
  
  function setValues(select) {
  const [v1, v2] = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.values.split(",");
  document.getElementById("field1").value = v1;
  document.getElementById("field2").value = v2;
}

  const select = document.getElementById("test");
  setValues(select);
  select.addEventListener("change", () => setValues(select));

</script>
```

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: Sorry? I would to know if there Is a solution to do this.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is there a error?  Which line? Debugging details?

Comment: I would to find a solution to auto-populate the others fields. As you can see the question i have written the code that take dynamically the data from a Spreadsheet in the select option, now I have asked how to proceed for the others fields.

Comment: Do the same thing like you did for the first column.  `getValues(A:C...)` and `data[i][1]` or `data[i][2]` as per the column you  want. Go ahead and try and try.

Comment: Sorry, but this Is the reason of the question, is that i don't know how to proceed in this case. If you would help me, I Will be very grateful.

Comment: In order to confirm whether my understanding of your goal is correct, can I ask you about your question? When an option, which is the value of column "A", is selected, you want to set the values from the column "B" and "C" to the input tags with the readonly. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, It Is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When an option, which is the value of column "A", is selected, you want to set the values from the column "B" and "C" to the input tags with the readonly.

### Modification points:

- In this modification, when `address()` is run at `<?!= address(); ?>`, the values of columns "A" to "C" are set to the options. The values of columns "B" and "C" are set to the custom attribute. And in HTML side, 2 input tags are added as `disabled="disabled"` you expect.
- When the other option is selected, the values of columns "B" and "C" are set to 2 input tags using Javascript.
- In your sample values of Spreadsheet, it seems that the 1st row is header row.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```
function address() {
  var sheet   =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx").getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + lastRow);  // Modified
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += `<option data-values="${data[i][1]},${data[i][2]}">${data[i][0]}</option>`;  // Modified
  };
  return optionsHTML;
}
```

#### HTML&Javascript side: `index.html`

In this modification, 2 input tags and Javascript were added.

```
<select class="custom-select" name="test" id="test">
  <?!= address(); ?>
</select>
<input type="text" id="field1" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" id="field2" disabled="disabled">

<script>
function setValues(select) {
  const [v1, v2] = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.values.split(",");
  document.getElementById("field1").value = v1;
  document.getElementById("field2").value = v2;
}

const select = document.getElementById("test");
setValues(select);
select.addEventListener("change", () => setValues(select));
</script>
```

### Note:

- Please use this Google Apps Script with enabling V8.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have applied your code, but the fields (B-C) are empty.

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because in my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. I apologize for this. So in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can do it, please add it to your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying and adding more information. In your case, for example, please move `<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>` to the bottom of `</body>` like `</div><?!= include('JavaScript'); ?></body>` or like `</body><?!= include('JavaScript'); ?></html>`, and test it again.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works! Naturally if i would to add some other columns in addition to B and C, which line of code I must to edit?

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you want to add more columns, please modify the line of `optionsHTML += ...` in Google Apps Script. And please modify the function of `setValues()` in Javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219943/discussion-between-popoff-and-tanaike).